# Building C++ translator with given dictionary?

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word

I am trying to build a simple translator that translates sentences based on given dictionary. Let's assume that we have two strings of words

```
string ENG[] = {"black","coffee", "want","yesterday"};
string SPA[] = {"negro", "café", "quiero", ayer"};
```

If user gives "I want a black coffee." the results should be "I? quiro a? negro cafe." It means for the words that has no translation in dictionary strings there should be question mark next to it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  string input string ENG[] = {"black", "coffee", "want", "yesterday"};
  string SPA[] = {"negro", "café", "quiero", "ayer"};

  cout << "Enter a word";
  cin >> input;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (ENG[i] == input) {
      cout << "You entered " << SPA[i] << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I have written converts just the words. How can I write this code and make it  possible for sentences?

Comment: Seems like there are quite a few missing characters in your code. Can you double check you've copied everything properly?

Comment: *How can I edit this code* -- By using a text editor.  Or do you mean "write the program to do this"?

Comment: Two "parallel arrays" like you're using is not a great way to store the data. Not only do you need to loop through all items to find a word, but it's also hard to maintain (insert one word wrong and everything after that will be wrong as well). Look into `unordered_map` (C++11 and up) or `map` (earlier versions).

Comment: Concerning this, the following article might be of interest: [Have “Machines” Surpassed Human Language Translation?](https://www.econtentpro.com/blog/have-machines-surpassed-human-language-translation/26). Translating sentences is a little bit more than replacing them word by word using a dictionary. Though there are some impressive results, if you prove things like google translate with sophisticated input then output becomes funny. (Although nearly everybody seems to fear that AI will overtake his/her job - I'm still laughing at it...)

Comment: I'm assuming you just want to simply replace the words in the sentence, not write an actual translating program with the grammar and stuff. You should break the problem down into small parts. Try figuring out how to separate the words in a sentence first. Then translate each word, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <string> split_sentence(const string& arg)
{

    vector <string> ret;

    auto it = arg.begin();
    while (it != arg.end()) {

        string tmp;

        while (it != arg.end() && *it == ' ') ++it;
        while (it != arg.end() && *it != ' ')
            tmp += *it++;

        if (tmp.size())
            ret.push_back(tmp);
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string input = "I want a black     coffee .";

    string ENG[4] = {"black","coffee", "want","yesterday"};
    string SPA[4] = {"negro", "café", "quiero", "ayer"};

    cout << "Enter sentence\n";
    /*
        cin >> input;
    */

    for (auto& str: split_sentence(input)) {

        bool found = false;

        for (int j=0; j<4 && !found; ++j) {

            if (ENG[j] == str) {
                cout << SPA[j] << " ";
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
            cout << str << "? ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter sentence
I? quiero a? negro café .?
```

Split the sentence by spaces and then find the appropriate word from dict.
If you're dict is `big enough` you need to use some tree like data structure to improve speed or sort and Hashing.

Edit:

```
Trie will be faster for this. For each query you 
can get the appropriate word in O(m), m = length of
query(English word)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, for this two separated arrays are really cumbersome to use and hard to update. Imagine inserting a new value pair in the middle and messing with the offsets…

So the far better solution here would be using a `std::map`, especially considering this is supposed to be a simple 1:1 mapping.

As such you can define a `std::map` using a `std::string` as a key (the original word) an a `std::string` as it's value (the translation).

When using modern C++, the initialization could look like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> translations {
    {"black", "negro"},
    {"coffee", "café"},
    // ...
};
```

Now as for getting your input string word by word, the quickest built-in way would be using `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream stream(myInputText);
std::string word;

while (stream >> word) {
    // do something with each word
}
```

Looking up the actual translations becomes trivial as well. Iterating over all translation happens in background (inside the `std::map` class):

```
const auto &res = translations.find(word);

if (res == translations.end()) // nothing found
    std::cout << "? ";
else
    std::cout << res->second << " "; // `res->second` is the value, `res->first` would be the key, i.e. `word`
```

As for a full tiny example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> translations {
        {"black", "negro"},
        {"coffee", "café"}
    };

    std::string source("I'd like some black coffee");
    std::istringstream stream(source);
    std::string word;

    while (stream >> word) {
        const auto &t = translations.find(word);

        if (t != translations.end()) // found
            std::cout << word << ": " << t->second << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << word << ": ???\n";
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This specific example would create the following output:

```
I'd: ???
like: ???
some: ???
black: negro
coffee: café
```